# Getting "network error" while downloading Eclipse ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I'm trying to download Eclipse ADT with Android sdk for windows from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download and whenever download reaches to 99 percent, i get an error "Failed-network error".What could be the solution to this problem? and I do already have Eclipse Indigo and also downloaded Stand-alone android SDK with API 10 and 14,but this combination is also not working properly, like while making android app it gives me errors such that: " parent class not found "Theme.AppCompact"  and "main is not a field"  " so on and so forth.  Also I do not find R.java file in my gen folder, and I have tried my best to remove these errors, searched solutions from Google  but none of the solution worked,that's why I'm trying to download "Eclipse ADT with Android sdk for windows" but get this "network-error" every time.

Comment: are you downloading 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: I'm downloading 64bit.Because I have windows 7 (64bit)

Comment: Let me download it now, and see if it works / fails for me

Comment: Are you using google crome? I faced same problem. But when I tried it on mozilla firefox, then download was completed.

Comment: yes I'm using Google Chrome.If browser is causing the error then I try again  with  Mozilla Firefox.Hope it would help and solve the problem.

Comment: Downloading with mozilla firefox didn't work for me. Download again failed!!